# Osticket - How do I assign a ticket to one person in a team?

Tags: ticket-system, osticket, ticket-tracking, trouble-tickets

I can't seem to understand how Osticket work. I looked everywhere I could for help in understanding how this system work, but without luck, hence I'm here. Can you explain the use of Departments, Groups and Teams? How do they work together? I like examples so please provide one, it would be much appreciated.

Anyways, I am trying to assign a ticket to one of 2 or more persons automatically. The ticket should remain in the open queue, but it should show that the ticket is assign to x person.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage automatic assignment in the "Admin panel".
Enter in "Manage > Help Topic", then click on one "Help topic" item. Now you will be able to see the drop down list "Auto-assign To". Choose the member and save.

Answer (score 0):

Staff is a staff person's account, or employee of the company that is using osTicket to track client issues. They can belong to a Department, Group, and/or Team.

Departments are an organizational unit [such as Billing or Installations, Collections, or Support]. Tickets are assigned to departments and as such a staff's department determines which tickets they can see and work on.

Groups are a security mechanism and are used to assign permissions to groups of users.  Things like "Can Create Tickets", "Can Edit Tickets", "Can Post Reply", etc. Groups can also control which departments group members can see.

Teams are a loose connection of Staff accounts that can be comprised of people from different departments. For example you could put Nancy from Support with John from Billing into a team to work on a project together as a way to transcend the security imposed by departments.